# Can not find file

Tags: java, junit, cmd

I run the program test like this

```
java -cp C:\Users\andrew\Project\selenium4j\lib\*;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\Temp\Test01
```

And it says to me:
Can not find file: C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\Temp\Test01
Can you help me?

Comment: Is Test01 a file or directory? Does it exist?

Comment: Yes. It does exist .class and .java files both

Comment: I'm not familiar with running tests from the command line with JUnitCore, but maybe you need to add the class name not path. i.e. `java -cp C:\Users\andrew\Project\selenium4j\lib\*;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test01`

Comment: Are you in running this program from  C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\Temp ?

Comment: If you're not running it from that directory, you should add the directory to the classpath, after the `.`.

Comment: Trisha java -cp C:\Users\andrew\Project\selenium4j\lib\*;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test01 forks fine, BUT I need to specifiy full path

Comment: sunrise76 Yes I run from C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: RealSkeptic  can you give me example????

Comment: @java_user I'm not sure what you mean by "specify full path"? Path for what?